# VBA: How to move value and offset for each subsequent value

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range, offset

I'm trying to paste each value in a loop on a differerent worksheet to a certain cell and then offset by 5 rows for each value I'm moving.

```
Dim counter As Variant, carModel As Variant 
Dim theRange As Range, row As Range, cell As Range
counter = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

Set theRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 7))
moveDest = Sheets("Destination").Cells(1, 1)


For Each row In theRange.Rows
    For Each cell In row
        carModel = cell.Cells(1)
        'paste this value into moveDest and move down 5 rows for the next cell loop
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for.

I removed your nested loop that isn't necessary for this. I also used a different method of getting the last row.

```
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim moveDest As Range
    
    Set moveDest = Sheets("Destination").Cells(1, 1)
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            .Cells(i, 1).Copy moveDest
            Set moveDest = moveDest.Offset(5, 0)
        Next i
    End With
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I did think my method of setting range was a little clunky, as well as my loops aha